# get data-attribute from function

Tags: javascript, jquery, flatpickr

I´m trying to get the `data-io` attribute from my function.

```
<input id="42297" class="edit flatpickr-input active" data-io="in" value="14:23" type="text" readonly="readonly">

onChange: function(selectedDates, time, instance){
```

With this code i can get my input id threw: `instance.input.id`
But i cannot figure out how to access the `data-io`attribute.

I´ve tried:

```
instance.input.data-io
instance.input.data('io')
instance.input.attr('data-io')
instance.input.attr('io')
```

How should i do?

Comment: Try `.dataset.io`.

Comment: @Walk Worked like a charm. Please write it down as an answer!

Comment: Okay, I will in a moment, glad it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `instance.input.dataset.io`. More information about data-* attributes here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Answer (score 0):

Since using `jQuery` use data-api:

```
$('#42297').data('io'); // -> in
```

Keep in mind that `id` should start with letter.

---

If your `instance.input` is JS object, convert it to jQuery: `$(instance.input).data('io')`

Comment: `Keep in mind that id should start with letter.`  just FYI, numerical `id` attributes are fine in HTML5

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, I know, that's why it's not `it must be`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery use either `.data('io')` or `attr('data-io')`. If using vanilla js, utilise [Element.getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute).

```js
var inp = document.getElementById('42297');
console.log(inp.getAttribute('data-io'));
var $inp = $('#42297');
console.log($inp.data('io'));
console.log($inp.attr('data-io'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="42297" class="edit flatpickr-input active" data-io="in" value="14:23" type="text" readonly="readonly">
```